# "No Module Named Requests" even though I installed pip, requests, and added it to PATH

Tags: python

```py
Error:
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I have done `python -m pip install requests`, have added that directory to my PATH, and have pip installed as well. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Either the install failed, you're using the wrong version of Python on your computer, or your IDE creates separate environments for projects and you need to install requests in that environment. You need to provide more information to get specific help.

Comment: Latest version of Python 3, install did not fail. Can you please elaborate on the third point?

Comment: To make this question perfectly clear, please try: `python -m pip install requests && echo "import requests" | python`.  This command gives you this error?

Comment: Hits me with a bunch of "Requirement already satisfied" in cmd, but the error still shows up in IDLE

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip3 install requests
```

It's possible that you also have python 2 installed, and "pip install" is installing the requests package for the wrong version of python. Good luck, hope it helps.